# Database: One table or two, what is the better approach?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Let's say I have an application, where user can write stories in languages.

When the user selects the language, there can be two situations:

1. User selects the language from the supported/official languages which are saved in one table.
2. The language user wants to select is not available in that table. So the user creates a custom language.

My question is: Where do I save those custom languages? Should I put them in the table with the "supported languages" or create a separate table?

I've been thinking about the following arguments:

**Separate tables:**

- Pro: Since custom languages are only available to the creator and supported languages available to all users, I search more often for supported languages. If there's a table with only supported languages, I need less time to find supported languages than if there was only one table for both supported and custom languages.
- Pro: There may be far more custom languages than supported languages, because various users may create the same custom language (is that really a pro argument?)
- Con: In other tables e. g. story table I need to save the language, and then I need two columns: one with the language id and one which tells whether it is a custom or a supported language.

**One table:**

- Con: I need an extra column to save if the language is officially supported or custom

Since I'me quite new to database design, I cannot decide, so I ask you: What is the better approach?

Comment: Same table, and an indicator field to say if the language is supported or not.  the language entity serves the same purpose in both cases.  What happens 2 years from now when you decide to support a language that has become popular? you have to move data and adjust joins.  By keeping it in the same entity; you just change data.

Comment: @xQbert thank you, can you explain please? :D

Comment: In relational database design data that contain the same entity information should be stored in the same table. One must consider the cardinality of that data to other data and if it is truly the same type of data.  if it is then why would you ever want to have 2 entities that have the same meaning in 2 different tables?  you like harder joins? more code? Or possibly a different approach involving a language profile table and language type tables which tell me which language is supported if you know there could be multiple attributes you need for a language.

Comment: The only time I would consider a different table here is if I know in the future the attributes of both types of languages could vary greatly making them not the same entity; but similar.  But in that case you'd be better off having a single table for the shared info and 2 sub tables off of the parent one for supported and one for notsupported  kinda like a class and subclass concept.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: your question might get closed, because (I think) there is no technically right answer, only various authors can tell you their personal opinion as an answer. So your question is primarily opinion based.

To stay with that: **my opinion** would be the extra column in one table. This would allow you to sort out quickly and it will also (and I think more important) allow users to regularly select a custom language, if it already exists (and if you don't block it by only showing non-custom languages to the user). This would reduce duplicate custom languages in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate table. More than any space constraints, you should worry about data consistency. Make sure your database is normalised. It's important on too many fronts.

> Analytics

Let's assume your application becomes viral and there are a lot of inserts going on. Some time in the future you might want to modify your table to store only the recent / live / current records for the user since universal data is not required. If you have just a single table, you'll actually end up over-writing a lot of original values (say, if you want to query -  what has been the most common custom language - it'll not be available since the original record is now lost).

> Performance

Different tables will give you the option to arrange the data which might be most optimised for read / write i.e. the way you select your indexes. Keeping a lot of data in a single table might impact your decision.

> Robust / Modularity

If you have a separate table for custom languages, you'll be able to alter that table as per your need. As you grow, a requirement might arise to insert a couple of more columns as attributes. It's not at all advisable to alter a voluminous table as it has the potential to put the system on lag (this'll become more prominent if you have just a single table and thrust everything there). Let's say, I develop an API to give you some sort of support for your custom languages. You might want to add my identifier as a record. It'll always be easier to alter a table that has only relevant data rather than changing a single table having universal dataset, which in any case is not advisable.

For this method to work perfectly, you'll need a design document stating all the constraints during inserts, the attributes where NULL will be allowed, how you'll manage one-to-many relationships (this'll require implementation of foreign keys) etc etc...

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a single "languages" reference table.

1. You would have to accumulate MANY, MANY, languages before you would be able to observe any performance impact.
2. your Schema would be simpler
3. the "language type" Lookup column could actually store numbers, which you can index and optimize any queries on the field.

Please let us know what you think!

Comment: thank you, can you please explain how I do this or where I can read something about that: the ""language type" Lookup column could actually store numbers, which you can index and optimize any queries on the field."

Comment: Search on the web or books specific to the database you are using (mySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, etc), specifically to learn about indexing.

Comment: You can add a column named "language_type", then use 1 for "supported" and 2 for "custom" (just for example).  Index this column.  Then, when querying for Supported language you could include "language_type = 1" in your Where clause.

Try to learn more about your chose DB and how to index columns.....

Answer (score 0):

Separate table. Unless you are optimizing very specifically for performance reasons, you should adhere to these principles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization